# Passing JSON object from ajax to PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am currently trying to pass a json object from ajax to php. But it does not get me anything..Below is my code. I already tried `print_r[$_POST]` it just returns `Array()`. What's wrong with this code?

This is my code: [screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlxms.png)

Comment: Please post code as text, not images. And please post your PHP code as well.

Comment: $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

Answer (score 0):

If ajax is sent with "GET" instead of "POST", you should use $ _GET in your code.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Are you sure that the Type parameter is post?

or use

```
print_r($_GET);
```